# "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it" using System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I'm having problems with playing sound using System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer, what is weird is how it works the first time around, however on the second time it throws an exception with the message of The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

This is my code below, look at m_BackgroundWorker_DoWork specifically which is where it actually plays the sound where the sound file location is different to the last stored one:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;
using System.Timers;
using System.Media;

namespace RPGInventor
{
    public partial class GameMapPanel : UserControl
    {
        protected Point m_Size;
        protected bool m_bGrid;
        protected CMap m_Map;
        protected System.Timers.Timer m_Timer;
        //protected SoundPlayer m_SoundPlayer;
        protected System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer m_SoundPlayer;
        protected string m_szLastMedia;
        protected bool m_bRepeatBGS;

        public GameMapPanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Width = 0;
            this.Height = 0;
            m_Size = new Point(0, 0);
            m_Timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000 / 60);
            m_Timer.Elapsed += m_Timer_Elapsed;
            //m_SoundPlayer = new SoundPlayer();
            m_SoundPlayer = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
            m_szLastMedia = "";
        }

        void m_Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Invalidate();
        }

        public void setupGrid(int nCols, int nRows)
        {
            this.Width = nCols * 32;
            this.Height = nRows * 32;
            m_Size = new Point(nCols, nRows);
            m_Map.setGridSize(nCols, nRows);

            GameDialog parent = (GameDialog)this.Parent;
            parent.updateScrollBars();
        }

        public void setMap(CMap map)
        {
            this.m_Map = map;
            MainForm mf = (MainForm)CUtil.findForm("RPG Inventor");

            //m_BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            m_BackgroundWorker_DoWork(null, null);

            for (int i = 0; i < getMap().getEvents().Count; ++i)
            {
                CEvent cevent = (CEvent)getMap().getEvents()[i];
                if (cevent.getType() == (int)CEvent.EventType.TRANSFER)
                {
                    CTransferEvent transferEvent = (CTransferEvent)cevent;

                    if (CResources.getLoadedMap(transferEvent.getMapName()) == null)
                    {
                        CMap temp = new CMap("", 0, 0);
                        CMap Loadmap = temp.retrieve(mf.m_Database, transferEvent.getMapName());
                        CResources.addLoadedMap(Loadmap);
                    }

                    CLayer layer = (CLayer)getMap().getMapLayers()[1];

                    CTransferObject transferObj = new CTransferObject(transferEvent);
                    transferObj.setLocation(new Point(transferEvent.getGridLoc().X * 32,
                    transferEvent.getGridLoc().Y * 32));

                    layer.addObject(transferObj, 2);
                }
                if (cevent.getType() == (int)CEvent.EventType.DOOR)
                {
                    CDoorEvent doorEvent = (CDoorEvent)cevent;

                    if (CResources.getLoadedMap(doorEvent.getMapName()) == null)
                    {
                        CMap temp = new CMap("", 0, 0);
                        CMap Loadmap = temp.retrieve(mf.m_Database, doorEvent.getMapName());
                        CResources.addLoadedMap(Loadmap);
                    }

                    CLayer layer = (CLayer)getMap().getMapLayers()[1];
                    CDoorObject doorObj = new CDoorObject(doorEvent);
                    int nH = doorObj.getHeight();
                    int nDiff = nH - 32;
                    int nY = (doorEvent.getGridLoc().Y * 32) - nDiff;
                    doorObj.setLocation(new Point(doorEvent.getGridLoc().X * 32, nY));

                    layer.addObject(doorObj, 2);
                }
            }
        }

        public CMap getMap()
        {
            return this.m_Map;
        }

        public void addCharacterSet(CCharacterSet charSet)
        {
            CSpriteObject spriteObj = new CSpriteObject();
            spriteObj.loadImage(charSet.CharGraphic);
            spriteObj.setAnimations(charSet.CharSize.Y, charSet.CharSize.X);
            spriteObj.setCharSet(charSet);
            spriteObj.setVisible(true);
            //spriteObj.setListener(this);

            for (int i=0; i<m_Map.getEvents().Count; ++i)
            {
                CEvent cevent = (CEvent) m_Map.getEvents()[i];
                if (cevent.getType() == (int)CEvent.EventType.PLAYER_START)
                {
                    int nSpaceY = 32; int nDifference = spriteObj.getHeight() - nSpaceY;
                    spriteObj.setLocation(new Point(cevent.getGridLoc().X * 32, 
                            (cevent.getGridLoc().Y * 32) - nDifference));
                }
            }

            CLayer layer = (CLayer)m_Map.getMapLayers()[1];
            layer.addObject(spriteObj, 2);
        }

        public void addCharacterSet(CCharacterSet charSet, Point ptGrid, int nDir)
        {
            GameDialog gd = (GameDialog)this.Parent;
            MainForm mf = (MainForm)gd.Owner;
            CSpriteObject spriteObj = new CSpriteObject();
            spriteObj.loadImage(charSet.CharGraphic);
            spriteObj.setAnimations(charSet.CharSize.Y, charSet.CharSize.X);
            spriteObj.setCharSet(charSet);
            spriteObj.setVisible(true);
            spriteObj.setLocation(new Point(ptGrid.X * 32, ptGrid.Y * 32));
            spriteObj.setDirection(nDir);
            spriteObj.setCurrentAnim(nDir);
            //spriteObj.setListener(this);

            CLayer layer = (CLayer)m_Map.getMapLayers()[1];
            layer.addObject(spriteObj, 2);
        }

        public void Closed()
        {
            m_SoundPlayer.Stop();
            m_SoundPlayer.Close();
        }

        private void GameMapPanel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //this.Height = 0;
            //this.Width = 0;
            GameDialog holder = (GameDialog)this.Parent;
            holder.updateScrollBars();
            m_Timer.Start();
        }

        private void GameMapPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

            //create back buffer
            Bitmap backBuffer = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
            Graphics backG = Graphics.FromImage(backBuffer);

            if (m_Map != null)
            {
                ArrayList mapLayers = m_Map.getMapLayers();

                for (int i = 0; i < mapLayers.Count; ++i)
                {
                    CLayer layer = (CLayer)mapLayers[i];
                    layer.DrawLayer(backG);
                }
            }

            g.DrawImage(backBuffer, new Point(0, 0));
        }

        private void GameMapPanel_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Focus();
        }

        private void GameMapPanel_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //get CharSet
            GameDialog gd = (GameDialog)this.Parent;
            MainForm mf = (MainForm)gd.Owner;
            CSpriteObject player = new CSpriteObject();
            CCharacterSet dbCharSet = (CCharacterSet)mf.m_Database.m_Characters[0];

            ArrayList list = m_Map.getMapLayers();
            CLayer layer = (CLayer)list[1];

            for (int i = 0; i < layer.getObjects().Count; i++)
            {
                CMapObject mapObj = layer.getObject(i);
                if (mapObj.getType() == (int)CMapObject.MapObjectType.SPRITE)
                {
                    CSpriteObject sprite = (CSpriteObject)mapObj;
                    if (sprite.getCharSet().Name.Equals(dbCharSet.Name))
                    {
                        player = sprite;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                player.setDirection((int)CSpriteObject.Direction.DOWN);
                player.startTimer();
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                player.setDirection((int)CSpriteObject.Direction.UP);
                player.startTimer();
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                player.setDirection((int)CSpriteObject.Direction.LEFT);
                player.startTimer();
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                player.setDirection((int)CSpriteObject.Direction.RIGHT);
                player.startTimer();
            }
        }

        private void GameMapPanel_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //get CharSet
            GameDialog gd = (GameDialog)this.Parent;
            MainForm mf = (MainForm)gd.Owner;
            CSpriteObject player = new CSpriteObject();
            CCharacterSet dbCharSet = (CCharacterSet)mf.m_Database.m_Characters[0];

            ArrayList list = m_Map.getMapLayers();
            CLayer layer = (CLayer)list[1];

            for (int i = 0; i < layer.getObjects().Count; i++)
            {
                CMapObject mapObj = layer.getObject(i);
                if (mapObj.getType() == (int)CMapObject.MapObjectType.SPRITE)
                {
                    CSpriteObject sprite = (CSpriteObject)mapObj;
                    if (sprite.getCharSet().Name.Equals(dbCharSet.Name))
                    {
                        player = sprite;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down || e.KeyCode == Keys.Up || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left || e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                player.stopTimer();
            }
        }

        private void GameMapPanel_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Down:
                case Keys.Up:
                case Keys.Left:
                case Keys.Right:
                    e.IsInputKey = true;
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void m_BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            MainForm mf = (MainForm)CUtil.findForm("RPG Inventor");

            if (this.getMap().getSoundDir() != null && this.getMap().getSoundDir() != ""
                && this.getMap().getSoundName() != null && this.getMap().getSoundName() != "")
            {
                String szPath = ".\\Projects\\" + mf.m_Database.m_Name + "\\Audio\\" +
                    this.getMap().getSoundDir() + "\\" + this.getMap().getSoundName();

                string szSoundPlayerPath = m_szLastMedia;

                if (!szSoundPlayerPath.Equals(szPath))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        m_SoundPlayer.Stop();
                        m_SoundPlayer.Open(new Uri(szPath, UriKind.Relative));
                        m_SoundPlayer.Play();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                    //m_SoundPlayer.Stop();
                    //m_SoundPlayer.SoundLocation = szPath;
                    //m_SoundPlayer.PlayLooping();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very big code example and a rather vague question, it would help if you could explain your problem domain more clearly and could provide a code example which isolates the problem you're having, rather than having  answerers try to sift through a lot of unrelated code to answer "what mistakes am I making?"

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WinForms, controls created in one thread cannot be accessed from any other thread. So you need to run the code on the main thread using `Invoke`.

Try this:

```
if (!szSoundPlayerPath.Equals(szPath))
{
    try
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate 
        {
            m_SoundPlayer.Stop();
            m_SoundPlayer.Open(new Uri(szPath, UriKind.Relative));
            m_SoundPlayer.Play();
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I'm not 100% sure if the above three lines are what's causing the exception, but you just need to wrap whatever lines of code are causing the error in the `Invoke` statement.

Answer (score 0):

When using a WPF element inside a different Thread than the UI thread you need to invoke using the Dispatcher.Invoke if you want a synchronous call, but if you can it is prefered to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke.

Change your code with:

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
    m_SoundPlayer.Stop();
    m_SoundPlayer.Open(new Uri(szPath, UriKind.Relative));
    m_SoundPlayer.Play();
}));
```

Comment: The OP is using WinForms

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your input, this is what I have come up with as a result and it works

```
if (InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            m_SoundPlayer.Stop();
                            m_SoundPlayer.Open(new Uri(szPath, UriKind.Relative));
                            m_SoundPlayer.Play();
                        }));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        m_SoundPlayer.Stop();
                        m_SoundPlayer.Open(new Uri(szPath, UriKind.Relative));
                        m_SoundPlayer.Play();
                    }
```